# При парсинге сайта выводиться None

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Учусь делать парсеры, решил сделать парсер avito, но при запуске программы выводиться None, как исправить

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

linc = 'https://www.avito.ru/all/telefony?cd=1&d=1&f=ASgCAQECAUD2vA0UlNI0AUXGmgwYeyJmcm9tIjozMDAwLCJ0byI6MjUwMDB9&s=104&user=1'
respoce = requests.get(linc).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(respoce,'lxml')

blok = soup.find('div',class_="items-items-kAJAg")
print(blok)
```

Comment: если вы посмотрите на вывод `print(respoce)`, то увидите, что того класса, который вы ищите нет, по этому вы и получаете пустой список